# <select> tag multiple property throws parser error using runat=server | object of type 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, runtime-error

### The Problem

**When using Visual Studio 2010 and attempting to write the following code:**

```
<select runat="server" multiple="multiple" id="prop_typeid" name="property_typeid" class="w290">
```

**a parser error occurs with the following:**

> Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation 'multiple' for the 'Multiple' property

The multiple="multiple" value is required in the code and is required for the jQuery 'jquery-ui-multiselect-widget' plugin by Eric Hynds.

According to [Microsoft's ASP.Net support](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/261833/select-tag-multiple-property-throws-parser-error-using-runat-server) they replied with:

> Thanks for notifying us about this bug. At this point we're taking only the severist of bugs to maintain high backward compatibility. This bug does not meet that bar and hence will not be fixed in the current product cycle.
>   A simple workaround is to use multiple="true". This should give you no compilation errors.

The value "true" works in IE but gives a warning in the UI that it is not a value of the multiple property.  If you are manipulating the DOM using jQuery the workaround fails too.

Comment: @Rory Why did you remove the jQuery tag? The above error happens in ASP.Net specifically due to jQuery multiselect requirements in the html output. Which I am assuming will be where most of the coders experiencing the above problem will come from.

Comment: So, whats the problem, as you asked and replied your own question at same time?

Comment: @Rubens I had the problem above and seeing as I couldn't find the answer on Google, even Microsoft's support hasn't solved the issue - I thought I'd post a solution for anybody else who experiences the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Solution

The issue with the IDE is at runtime, the ASP.NET rendering engine also stutters in the same way when using some databinding expressions. So in this case the rendering engine can be tricked to ignore the 'multiple' property for rendering by prefixing the multiple attribute with <kbd>meta:</kbd> , but still execute the code, like so:

```
<select runat="server" meta:multiple="multiple" id="prop_typeid" name="property_typeid" class="w290">
```

Using 'meta:' in this way successfully renders the select property with the jQuery multiselect widget working nicely.  It also allows me to manipulate the select property in code behind by, for example, identifying and assigning the selected state option from the database -

***A Codebehind Example below :***

```
if (db.prop_typeid != null)
{
    ListItem li = prop_typeid.Items.FindByValue(db.prop_typeid.ToString());
    li.Selected = true;
}
```

Prefixing 'meta:' in this way can be used for various properties on runat=server situations where the above type error occurs to ensure that the rendering engine processes asp.net pages.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this, you can easily set `multiple` attribute in `Page_Load`:

```
yourSelectId.Attributes["multiple"] = "multiple";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also achieve this by jQuery once the page has finished load and body is formed:

```
$(window).load(function () {
         $('#chkDC').attr('multiple', 'multiple')

     });
```